# XCODE, dealloc called only after removeFromSuperView

Tags: xcode, dealloc

I have xib, h and m files for custom view, subclass of UIView. I add this custom view to UIVIewControlloer's view. But when I call

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

UIViewController's dealloc method calls, but dealloc method os custom view - not. If I remove custom view from controller's view (removeFromSuperview), 
both methods calling. I have no idea why ...

Answer (score 0):

In method in custom class was passed UIView as Strong param. Change to weak and everything is ok now.